# Include different JS script depending if run inside chrome extension or web

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developping a chrome extension AND web js application.
I have an HTML container.

I need this container.html having

```
<script src="extension.js">
```

when running in chrome extension and

```
<script src="web.js">
```

when running in web version

**(But Cannot have both at the same time)**

Any idea how to include either 1 script either other depending if running in extension or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have some property or global object that is available only in chrome extension environment, for example: `chrome.cookies`. Then you could check the existence of that object or property and load dinamically the javascript file, for example:

```
function loadScript(url, callback){

    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    script.onload = function(){
        callback();
    }
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

if(chrome && chrome.cookies){
    loadScript('extension.js', function(){ //loaded })
}
else{
    loadScript('web.js', function(){ //loaded })
}
```

Comment: This must be done in a js file as it is blocked by Chrome's security policy if done in the html file <script> section.